# Pass a list as a function argument in Python to download multiple surveys from Qualtrics

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, qualtrics

I have been using [this](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/Python-Tool-Downloading-Qualtrics-Survey-Data-using-Python-API/td-p/304898) to extract Qualtrics surveys from my Qualtrics admin portal. This code is totally working fine but my question is that I would like to use this code on to a list of Survey ids and then download each file one after other.

How can I achieve this?

The code that I am using from the above link is :

```
def get_qualtrics_survey(dir_save_survey, survey_id):
   # Setting user Parameters
   api_token = "token"
   file_format = "csv"
   data_center = 'xx' # "<Organization ID>.<Datacenter ID>"

# Setting static parameters
request_check_progress = 0
progress_status = "in progress"
base_url = "https://{0}.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/".format(data_center)
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-token": api_token,
}

# Step 1: Creating Data Export
download_request_url = base_url
download_request_payload = '{"format":"' + file_format + '","surveyId":"' + survey_id + '"}' # you can set useLabels:True to get responses in text format
download_request_response = requests.request("POST", download_request_url, data=download_request_payload, headers=headers)
progress_id = download_request_response.json()["result"]["id"]
# print(download_request_response.text)

# Step 2: Checking on Data Export Progress and waiting until export is ready
while request_check_progress < 100 and progress_status != "complete":
    request_check_url = base_url + progress_id
    request_check_response = requests.request("GET", request_check_url, headers=headers)
    request_check_progress = request_check_response.json()["result"]["percentComplete"]

# Step 3: Downloading file
request_download_url = base_url + progress_id + '/file'
request_download = requests.request("GET", request_download_url, headers=headers, stream=True)

# Step 4: Unzipping the file
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(request_download.content)).extractall(dir_save_survey)
print('Downloaded qualtrics survey')

## the below list contains the survey ids that I want to download
lst = ['1','2','3']
##calling the function
path = r"C:\Users\Downloads"
get_qualtrics_survey(dir_save_survey=path, survey_id = lst)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for survey in lst:    
    get_qualtircs_survey(dir_save_survey=path, survey_id=survey)
```

""" Explanation:
Since the survey ids are downloaded one at a time, you have to iterate through the list of ids, passing them to the function singularly and not all at once.

What I also found works really well are these functions:"""

```
!pip install QualtricsAPI
from QualtricsAPI.Setup import Credentials
from QualtricsAPI.Survey import Responses
# and so on...
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**